# How to solve a double integration with two different region that have different bound?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

The height of the equation is $z= x^3 +4y$  and it is bounded by $Y = x^3$ and $Y = 2x$, I have drawn the bounded region below.
As you can see, for the left region if we take the double integration of the type 1 area it is bounded from $2x$ to $x^3$, and the right region is bounded from $x^3$ to $2x$, how do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Vanishing integral due to symmetry

Answer (score 1):

Note that both the areas (Area in $1$st quadrant and $3$rd quadrant) are similar. We can find any of the areas and multiply by $2$ to find the desired area.

For the area in $1$st quadrant, consider vertical elemental strips with length $dx$ going from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$ and for height, the upper limit is given by $y=2x$ and the lower limit by $y = x^3$.

**Area in first quadrant is given by,**
$$A = \int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{x^3}^{2x} (x^3 + 4y) \ dy dx $$

Can you take it from here? (Solving this double integral is not a hard task tbh).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so if there's more multiple region all i have to do is integrate them separately and add them ?

Comment: @KCN Yeah, that will work.